# how to change the foreground color of the RadDatePicker in windows phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, telerik, windows-phone-8

Hi i am using telerik rad controls for windows phone 8 in my windows phone 8 app.

**My doubt is :-**

i want to change the foreground color of my date picker (want to change the foreground color of the date).

i tried setting in this way :-

```
 <telerikcontrols:RadDatePicker  Foreground="Black" 
 x:Name="DatePicker1" PopupClosed="DatePicker1_PopupClosed_1"
 PopupOpened="DatePicker1_PopupOpened_1"  Margin="141,254,139,-247"
 Height="83" Width="162" />
```

but it didnt work , how can i se the foreground colour .

note :- i am having an image as background to that entire screen , thats not creating the prolem right ??

please let me know .

looking forward for your reply .

thanks in advance.

Comment: Styling the RadDatePicker can be found in the documentation: http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/raddatepicker-styles-and-templates-overview.html